# Reload chrome extension after taking user input from options page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension, which shows some options on right click. There is an options page where the user can enter his preferences(what options to show on right click and what not to). When the user's preferences are saved, they are not reflected in the behavior of the extension until it is reloaded or chrome is restarted. How can I avoid this? I want the changes to come into effect immediately.

Comment: Can you show your code? It might help others point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reload your extension by reloading the background page:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().window.location.reload()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works neatly :)

Comment: Finally, a proper solution. Thank you!